# Mensagem "Invalid object name 'dbo.table' SQL Server com Go Lang

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, github, golang, microsoft-azure

Estou tentando usar um select em meu Banco de Dados SQL Server que possuo no Azure.

Estou usando o Driver: https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb.

Porem, é me retornado uma mensagem:

> mssql: Invalid object name 'dbo.table'.

Abaixo meu código, onde estou errado?

```
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    connectionDB() // inicia conexão com o azure
}

func connectionDB() {

    log.Println("Main:")
    log.Println("Opening")

    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", "server=pwbt.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=dbo;user id=admin-jose;password=password") //deixei a senha errada para postar aqui

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Open Failed: ", err.Error())
    }

    log.Println("Opened")
    log.Println("Pinging")

    err = db.Ping();
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to ping: ", err.Error())
    }

    log.Println("Pinged")

    x := 2
    rows, err := db.Query("select Nome from dbo.tbPessoa where Id=?", x)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()
    defer db.Close()    
    fmt.Println(rows)
    fmt.Printf("bye\n")
}
```

Retorno:

> C:\Go\bin\go.exe run B:\go\gocode\src\main\connect-bd.go
>   2017/02/25 15:59:33 Main:
>   2017/02/25 15:59:33 Opening
>   2017/02/25 15:59:33 Opened
>   2017/02/25 15:59:33 Pinging
>   2017/02/25 15:59:33 Pinged
>   2017/02/25 15:59:33 mssql: Invalid object name 'dbo.tbPessoa'.
>   exit status 1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Na minha connect String faltava dizer qual Banco vou usar `database=PWBT.`

Feito isto conectou numa boa!

Sem esta informação o Select estava sendo feito no banco "master" padrão do SQL.

Ficou assim:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mssql", "server=pwbt.database.windows.net;user id=admin-jose;password=password;database=PWBT;port=1433")
```